# PHPExcel How to upload excel file in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I generated one excel file using PHPExcel now I need to upload that Excel file after fill necessary data in excel file. I tried to search any tutorial or proper /specific documentation on uploading excel data in MySQL table 
Here is code by which I am creating and downloading Excel File.

```
<?php
$host='localhost'; $user='vishal'; $pass='wh0FOR'; $DataBase='school';//define the correct values
// open the connexion to the databases server
$Link=@mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$DataBase) or die('Can\'t connect !');
mysqli_set_charset($Link, 'utf8');//if not by default

//your request
$SQL="SELECT `admissionnumber`,`pre_name`,`pre_fathersoccupation`,`pre_motheroccupation` FROM `es_preadmission` WHERE `pre_class`=25 AND `pre_fromdate`>='2014-04-01' AND `pre_todate`<='2015-03-31'";
$rs=mysqli_query($Link, $SQL);//get the result (ressource)
$SQL1="SELECT a.`total_marks`,a.`pass_marks`,b.es_subjectname FROM `es_exam_details` as a JOIN `es_subject` as b ON a.`subject_id`=b.`es_subjectid` JOIN es_exam_academic as c ON c.es_exam_academicid=a.academicexam_id WHERE es_subjectshortname=25";
$rs1=mysqli_query($Link, $SQL1);//get the result (ressource)
$SQL2="SELECT distinct(b.es_subjectname) as subjects FROM `es_exam_details` as a JOIN `es_subject` as b ON a.`subject_id`=b.`es_subjectid` JOIN es_exam_academic as c ON c.es_exam_academicid=a.academicexam_id WHERE es_subjectshortname=25";

$rs2=mysqli_query($Link, $SQL2);//get the result (ressource)
while($objResult1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2)){
    $subjects[] = $objResult1["subjects"];
} 
while($objResult =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs1)){
    $totalmarks[] = $objResult["total_marks"];
    $term[] = $objResult["aca_term_name"]; 
}

$totalStudents=array();
while($objResult =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$totalStudents[] = $objResult;
}

$Sa1Sa2marks=60;
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// read in the existing file
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("blank.xls");

// modify/insert data in worksheet cells
$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
     'outline' => array(
        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
           'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),
             ),
       ),
       'fill' => array(
          'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
          'color' => array('rgb' => '686868')
        )
);

$F=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$G=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$G->getProtection()->setSheet(true);

// for 1st row heading subject heading setting 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A1:B1")->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,1, "Subject");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:B1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A3:B3")->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,3, "Exam");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:B3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);

// for 4th row heading subject heading setting 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A4', "ROLL");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B4', "NAME");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

//subject list setting
$row=1;
$coumnStart=1;
$subjectCtr=0;
foreach($subjects as $subject)
{   
$coumnStart++;
$StartcolumnIndex=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($coumnStart);
$EndcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($coumnStart-1) + 13);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.$row.':'.$EndcolumnIndex.$row)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart,1, $subject)$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.$row)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER); $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.$row.':'.$EndcolumnIndex.$row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($coumnStart-1) + 6)
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart,2, 'TERM 1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+1))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$coumnStart;
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'SA1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;
$StartcolumnIndex2=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($coumnStart) + 6);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($coumnStart + 12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex2.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart+6,2, 'TERM 2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex2.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA3');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA4');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'SA2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart+12,4, 'PERCENTAGE');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($totalMarksColumIndex.($row+3))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($totalMarksColumIndex.($row+3))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($totalMarksColumIndex)->setWidth(20);
$flag=1;
for($i=$coumnStart;$i<$coumnStart+12;$i=$i+1)
{
$MarksheadingIndex=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i);    
 if($flag%2==1) 
  {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,4, 'MARKS');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($MarksheadingIndex)->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
  }
 else 
  {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,4, 'MAXMARKS');
      for($j=5;$j<count($totalStudents)+5;$j++){
        if($flag%6==0)
        {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$j, $Sa1Sa2marks);    
        }
        else if($flag==2 || $flag==8)
        {
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$j, 40);  
        }
        else
        {
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$j, 20);     
        }
      }
  }
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($MarksheadingIndex)->setWidth(15);
$flag++;    
}

$coumnStart=($coumnStart-1)+13; $subjectCtr++;
}

// putting students name with rollno

$Line=5;
 foreach($totalStudents as $student){//extract each record
        $studentName= $student['pre_name'];
        if($student['pre_fathersoccupation']!=''){$studentName.=' '.$student['pre_fathersoccupation'];}
        if($student['pre_motheroccupation']!=''){$studentName.=' '.$student['pre_motheroccupation'];}
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$Line,  $student['admissionnumber']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$Line,  $studentName);
    ++$Line;
       }

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="newFile.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output'); 

?>
```

If any one give some link or any guidance it will really help me to come out of my importing of data from excel to mysql problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is best plugin with proper documentation and examples

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Friend I searched for ample of time and then I posted this question here. This is know to every that programmer who need better Excel PHP MySQL communication. It will help more if you can give or suggestion something precise.

Answer (score 0):

Use output buffering to save your phpexcel output into a variable as per [How do I write my excel spreadsheet into a variable, using PhpExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469779/how-do-i-write-my-excel-spreadsheet-into-a-variable-using-phpexcel)

And then store the output into a MySQL BLOB. I don't think you'd need to serialize it, but look into what needs to happen depending on what MySQL tells you and report back to us :)